# Finding the sum of a series, don't understand how they get from one step to the next

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

[image]

Can some one please explain how they get from the red boxed step to the blue boxed one?

Comment: Write out more terms and see that everything else cancels.

Comment: It's known as a telescoping series.

Comment: Hmmm, alright. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it should be obvious that they factored the $3$ out of the whole thing.

Secondly, we will note that the remainder is given as:

$$(\frac12-\frac14)+(\frac13-\frac15)+(\frac14-\frac16)+\dots(\frac1{k}-\frac1{k+2})$$

Rewriting it without parenthesis,

$$\frac12-\frac14+\frac13-\frac15+\frac14-\frac16+\frac15-\frac17+\dots\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}$$

Now if you look closely, you will note what I have highlighted.

$$\frac12\color{red}{-\frac14}+\frac13\color{blue}{-\frac15}\color{red}{+\frac14}\color{green}{-\frac16}\color{blue}{+\frac15}\color{orange}{-\frac17}+\dots\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}$$

Each term that I highlighted corresponds to another term of the same color.  If you notice, these two terms will cancel each other.

After all of the cancellations occur, the only remaining terms are

$$\frac11+\frac13-\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+2}$$

This type of summation is called a [telescoping series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac12-\frac14$$

$$\frac13-\frac15$$

$$\frac14-\frac16$$

$$\frac15-\frac17$$

$$・$$

$$・$$

$$・$$

$$\frac1{k-3}-\frac1{k-1}$$

$$\frac1{k-2}-\frac1{k}$$

$$\frac1{k-1}-\frac1{k+1}$$

$$\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}$$

$\frac14, \frac15, \frac1{k-1}, \frac1k$ are vanished.hope for help.